# PostgreSQL, ошибка при INSERT/UPDATE в таблицу связанную с наследованнаой таблицей

Tags: postgresql

```
create table users(
    id serial,
    namea text
);

create table members(
    nameb text,
    CONSTRAINT members_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
) inherits(users);

create table tokens(
    id serial,
    uid integer references users(id) on delete cascade on update cascade,
    value text
);

insert into members(namea, nameb)values('foo','bar'); --it's ok!

select * from users; --it's ok too. The user with id = 1 is exists

insert into tokens(uid, value)values(1, 'foo'); --there are errors
INSERT or UPDATE table "tokens" violates foreign key constraint "tokens_user_id_fkey"
DETAILS: The key (user_id) = (1) is not in the table "users".
```

but the user with id = 1 is exists, why does it happens?

Comment: К сожалению с Postgers не работал и под руками нет. Но вот его сообщение `DETAILS: The key (user_id) = (1) is not in the table "users"` мне кажется очень странным. как будто у вас есть какой то отдельный фореджен ссылающийся на поле `user_id` в какой то другой таблице ... просто в описаниях ваших таблиц поля с именем `user_id` вообще нет. предлагаю посмотреть какие вообще есть фореджены в системе

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да откуда же взяться записи users.id=1? Нет её в таблице, ибо инзертили вы только в members. Members, в свою очередь, унаследована от users, посему выборка из юзерс отображает и записи в members. Выполните

```
select * from only users
```

и данной записи уже не найдёте.

**Дополнение** (добрался до PC и могу себе позволить написать более развернутый ответ). Попробуем разобраться, что же все таки происходит и как с этим бороться

Создается таблица users

```
create table users(
    id serial,
    namea text
);
```

Далее создается наследованная от users таблица members

```
create table members(
    nameb text,
    CONSTRAINT members_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
) inherits(users);
```

На этом моменте остановимся по подробнее. Таблица members наследует все поля от таблицы users, плюс имеет свое поле nameb. Также, создается примарный ключ по id. Однако, этот примарный ключь действителен исключительно на таблицу members, ведь у нее свое поле id. Грубо говоря, наследование, есть создание **отдельной** таблицы, с той лишь разницей, что часть ее структуры "скопирована" из наследуемой и дополнительный бонус в виде возможности обращения к записям наследованной таблицы из неследуемой (т.е. users видит записи members, но только наследованные поля, личные поля members, в частности nameb, ей не доступны). Из этого следует, что в users и members могут быть свои записи с конкретным id.

Далее, создается таблица tokens

```
create table tokens(
    id serial,
    uid integer references users(id) on delete cascade on update cascade,
    value text
);
```

На этом пункте также остановимся. Во первых, хотелось бы уточнить у автора, действительно ли именно приведенный листинг запускался на тестируемой базе, если так, то какая версия PostgreSQL использовалась. Дело в том, что хоть данный код синтаксически верен, он не применим к текущей структуре базы. Таблица users была создана с автоинкрементируемым полем id, но индекса уникальности на ней нет, т.е. она позволяет создать более одной записи с конкретным id и попытка создания таблицы tokens с foreign key на users(id) должно приводить к ошибке:

> there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table
>   "users"

Т.е. users должна была создаваться, к примеру, так

```
create table users(
    id serial unique,
    namea text
);
```

Теперь есть гарантия того, что в users не будет записей с одним и тем же id и создание таблицы tokens со ссылкой uid на users.id отработает без ошибок.

Далее, заносим запись в members

```
insert into members(namea, nameb)values('foo','bar'); --it's ok!
```

Останавливаться особо не на чем, выполняем следующую строку листинга

```
select * from users; --it's ok too. The user with id = 1 is exists
```

В этой сроке сделаны неверные выводы. Запрос действительно возвращает запись с id=1, но это запись не из users, а из members (поскольку members наследована от users, то она видна и из users). Следующий код тому подтверждение, он не выдаст ни одной записи, т.к. имеется условие выборки только из users не беря во внимание наследованные таблицы:

```
select * from only users;
```

Именно по этой причине следующий код и не работает

```
insert into tokens(uid, value)values(1, 'foo'); --there are errors
```

Ведь uid должен ссылаться на users.id, а такой записи в users нет.

Как получить желаемое? Во первых, вспомним тот факт, что id в members и users не связаны и в обоих таблицах может быть своя запись с тем же id. Соответсвенно, нельзя сделать foreign key, который бы учитывал и записи наследуемой и наследованной таблицы. Значит, нужно искать иные решения.

1. Отказаться от проверок на базе, тем самым возлагая заботу целостности базы на клиента (не очень удачное решение)
2. Воспользоваться тригерами, которые и будут проверять возможность вставки/изменения записей в tokens поддерживая целостность базы
3. Изменить структуру базы (действительно, а так ли в данном случае нужно наследование? Какова цель внедрения наследования?)

При тригерном решении, также не помешают тригеры на users/members, которые бы обновляли tokens.uid при изменениях users.id, members.id (или напрочь запрещали бы это делать). Тригерами же можно решить и проблему одного id в users и members.

**Дополнение 2** Что-то так разошелся в пояснениях, что не увидел вполне очевидного решения. Возможно, tokens.uid просто должен ссылаться на members.id? Вообще, цель наследования пока покрыта мраком, как по мне, так стоит пересмотреть структуру базы, не вижу острой необходимости в наследовании.

Comment: А как тогда сделать, insert чтобы ограничения обойти?

Comment: @exru, дополнит ответ расширенным объяснением происходящего и вариантами решения.

Comment: В общем мы отказались от использования наследования в проекте т.к. это наследование "ватное". Была бы прекрасная киллер-фича inherits. Просто хотелось, чтобы таблицы members и staff(не упоминается!) были частью чего-то общего c таблицей users. К примеру зарегистрировал участника торгов и\или зарегил. нового модератора, а авторизация уже готова через сущность юзера. Пришлось всё сделать стандартными релейшенами. Ну, и по сути такие вот ошибки считаю за баг. Зачем делать функционал, который семантически не соответствует заявленному смыслу. Это не наследование - это фантомная(мнимая) вылазка.

Comment: С багом вы крепко погорячились. Если вы не разобравшись в спецификации функционала принялись использовать его как вам показалось верным - это баг не функционала, а использования. К примеру, в некотором проэкте данный функционал успешно использоуется с 5-6 вложенными наследованиями от одной до >7000 таблиц на самом нижнем уровне. Ваша же задача решается тупыми присваиваниями юзерам соответсвующих групп.